# Validating a cloned/repeatable input (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, theme-options, validation

I'm trying to create a repeatable field an upload image input with image preview for my Theme Options page and I have the following:

```
function theme_options_validate( $_POST ){

if (isset($_POST['submit']) ) {
$theme_options = array();
    foreach ($_POST['image'] as $key => $value) {
        if (empty($value))  continue; 
        $theme_options[] = array(
            'image'     => $_POST['image'][$key],
        );
    }
$valid_input['image'] = $_POST['image'][$key];
}

return $valid_input;

}
```

for this input:

```
<input type="hidden" class="image" name="custom_options[image][]" value="<?php echo esc_url( $theme_options['image'] ); ?>" />
```

So far, everything works fine, the problem is that I'm using jQuery `.clone()` to clone this input and add more images, but the clone always overwrite the original input when submitting!

Tried using jQuery to count the input as well(`name="custom_options[image][0],[1],[2]`..."), but have had no luck, the clone never returns.

Any idea on how can I fix this?

Comment: Well you need to show use the `.clone` code, but this sounds more like a jQuery question.